# Trying to read a file and put values in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to read certain portions of a file and put them into their correct array.

```
public static void load(String fileName, String[] itemNumbers,
        String[] itemNames, double[] priceOfItem, int[] quantity) throws IOException{
    int i = 0;
    File inFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(inFile);
    while(reader.hasNext()){
        itemNumbers[i] = reader.next();
        itemNames[i] = reader.next();
        priceOfItem[i] = reader.nextDouble();
        quantity[i] = reader.nextInt();
        i++;
    }
    //This is just to see if it worked
        System.out.println(itemNumbers[i]);
        System.out.println(itemNames[i]);
        System.out.println(priceOfItem[i]);
        System.out.println(quantity[i]);    
}
```

Here is the file I'm reading.

```
E3233 CordlessDrill 129.99 12
W2321 WindowSealer 3.39 84
```

The arrays are in order with the file portions.
When I run this I receive the following

```
null
null
0.0
0
```

Comment: After the loop the variable `i` points to a position in the arrays that you did not use (so the first unused position of the arrays). So use `i-1` in `System.println.out(itemNumbers[i-1])` (and if you may change the interface you should use lists: they can grow dynamically whereas an array has a fixed size and that might to lead to the situation that you want to read more items but there is no free slot in the arrays left).

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that. It's so obvious now!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it says
while(reader.hasNextLine())

Comment: Tried that but I still got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using FileReader?

```
public static void load(String fileName, String[] itemNumbers,
    String[] itemNames, double[] priceOfItem, int[] quantity) throws  IOException{
    File inFile = new File(fileName);

    char[] cbuf = new char[(int) inFile.length()];

    FileReader r = new FileReader(inFile);
    r.read(cbuf);
    String finalString = String.valueOf(cbuf);
    String[] lines = finalString.split("\n");

    itemNumbers = new String[lines.length];
    itemNames = new String[lines.length];
    priceOfItem = new double[lines.length];
    quantity = new int[lines.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        String line = lines[i].replace("\n", "");
        String[] values = line.split(" ");
        String itemNumber = values[0];
        String itemName = values[1];
        double price = Double.parseDouble(values[2]);
        int quant = Integer.parseInt(values[3].replace(String.valueOf((char)13), "").replace(" ", "").replace("\"", ""));
        itemNumbers[i] = itemNumber;
        itemNames[i] = itemName;
        priceOfItem[i] = price;
        quantity[i] = quant;
    }
    r.close();
        for(int i = 0; i < itemNames.length; i++){
            System.out.println(itemNumbers[i]);
            System.out.println(itemNames[i]);
            System.out.println(priceOfItem[i]);
            System.out.println(quantity[i]);
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
}
```

this method relies on using spaces in your file, I would add comma's and end lines with semicolons to be safe, but if you maintain the same format this should work.